# Not able to wget a external servicers through DNS although it can be possible through ip address from Openshift POD

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

We are configuring our app in OCP (Openshift) through `Docker container`. In the deployment config we have mentioned the `hostAliases` field under `spec.template`in the following way

```
  template:
        hostAliases:
            - ip: 123.123.123.123
              hostnames:
              - sample.example.com
```

But after we create a deployment from this deploymentconfig,it starts. But we are not able to do the following operation.

```
wget http://sample.example.com:1234/example/rest
```

It gives bad address error. Although we can do the same call through it's ip

```
wget http://123.123.123.123/example/rest
```

When we import the deployment config, it will start the deployment but after deployment we are not able to find the `hostAliases` field in the yaml.

Please tell me how do we create the external service call through it's dns.

Comment: exec into the pod and check the content of `/etc/hosts` file..if it has got the entry

Comment: No. it does not have any entry in `/etc/hosts`